# .xpsf file: is username / password sent unecrypted?

Tags: encryption, rtsp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
    <trackList>
        <track><location>rtsp://username:password@myFQDN:554/live/ch00_0</location><title>Full resolution</title></track>

    </trackList>
</playlist>
```

A .xpsf has been configured to point to a stream for use for use with VLC LAN: is the username:password sent uncrypted?  What is the simplest (easiest) way to verify?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to verify this is to analyse your network traffic using a tool like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org).